# Can I declare a template to only accept functions with homogeneous signature?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, template-argument-deduction

I have a set of duple of functions, each taking `N` arguments of type `T`, with an additional argument of type `X` for the second one.

For `N=2`, `T=int` and `X=std::vector<int>` the duple would be something like this:

```cpp
void my_function2(int x1, int x2) {}
void my_function2(int x1, int x2, std::vector<int> other) {}
```

I am trying to write a templated high order function to which I pass the first function.

This will work for `N=2`:

```cpp
template <typename R, typename T>
int my_hof(R(*param)(T, T)) { param(1,2); }

my_hof(&my_function2); // compiles
```

Making the signature of `param` explicit is important because otherwise the template instantiation would fail because of "Unresolved overloaded function type". The point is to eliminate the second overload of `my_function2()`.

My problem is that I can not think of a way to generalize this to `N`. I tried using a variadic template:

```cpp
template <typename R, typename ...X> 
struct make_signature { using type = R(*)(int, int); };
// Cheating a big on make_signature not to clutter the question
// But the idea would be to repeat the same type N times.

template <typename R, typename ...X>
int my_generalized_hof(typename make_signature<R, X...>::type param) {
    f(1,2); // cheating a bit on the call too 
}

my_generalized_hof(&my_function2); // does not compile
```

I guess the compiler gets confused as the type of `param` is not given straightaway, it can't decide which overload to use to do the type computation. ("unresolved overloaded function type again"). I think it would also refuse to do the type computation anyway as it could not deduce the type of `R`.

I can't think of a way to generate the signature.

Is it possible to write this in C++ ?

(Note that I know I could select the overload by casting `my_function2()` to the right type when calling `my_generalized_hof()`, but I'd like to avoid that)

Comment: If we don't know what `N` is beforehand we would theoretically have to through an infinite number of "`X`s" to find the right overload. And there's no way to deduce `N` from `f` if `f` is overloaded.

Comment: Agreed ! I think what I'm looking for is some kind of hack really. Like some kind of way to "lazily" generate `my_generalized_hof` with the right number of arguments. Or some way of deactivating the function before the template parameter deduction.
Ideally no macro :)

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following `make_signature`

```
template <typename T, std::size_t>
using getType = T;

template <typename, typename, std::size_t N,
          typename = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct make_signature;

template <typename R, typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Is>
struct make_signature<R, T, N, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
 { using type = R(*)(getType<T, Is>...); };
```

But there is a problem: when you write

```
template <typename R, typename T, std::size_t N>
void my_generalized_hof (typename make_signature<R, T, N>::type param)
 {
   // do something with param
 }
```

the `make<R, T, N>` part is in no-deduced-context (is before `::`), so `R`, `T`, and `N` can't be deduced from the argument.

I mean... you can't call

```
 my_generalized_hof(&my_function2);
```

You have to explicit the template arguments as follows

```
 // ...............VVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
 my_generalized_hof<void, int, 2u>(&my_function2);
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

void my_function2(int x1, int x2) {}
void my_function2(int x1, int x2, std::vector<int> other) {}

template <typename T, std::size_t>
using getType = T;

template <typename, typename, std::size_t N,
          typename = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct make_signature;

template <typename R, typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Is>
struct make_signature<R, T, N, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
 { using type = R(*)(getType<T, Is>...); };

template <typename R, typename T, std::size_t N>
void my_generalized_hof (typename make_signature<R, T, N>::type param)
 {
   // do something with param
 }

int main ()
 {
   my_generalized_hof<void, int, 2u>(&my_function2); 
 }
```

Comment: That does work, but it's quite equivalent to casting `my_function2` to the the signature you want. I'd like to avoid that ideally (reason being I'm changing a function that is called in many many places). I would like to make my template smart enough to pick the homogeneous overload by itself.

Comment: @bkhantun - Is seems to me that you want a template too much smart: that select a function pointer given a signature and that select a signature given a function pointer. It seems to me a chicken and egg problem. But I'm curious and I hope that someone can find a solution.